# Access Phonegap SQLite data using java in android

Tags: java, html, cordova, android-sqlite, web-sql

Am developing an android app using `HTML5 and Phonegap`.
App contains a database which developed using [Phonegap Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)..

Is there any possibility to access the database of the application using `Java`?

90% of my application is developed using HTML5 but , I have a requirement to add Java and access the data from Database(created by phonegap) using Java.

How can i do this? is there any possibility ? Please guide me.

Comment: why would want to reinvent the wheel you can use the sqlite plugin ( written in Java ) to access the sqlite database through JavaScript. link for plugin over [here](https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

Comment: @frank  : Can we access the Database values (sqlite plugin ) using Java?  is this possible?

Comment: Its a plugin so that you can access database values in HTML/JavaScript. why would you want to access database values in Java, when u r writing an HTML5 App?

Comment: @frank : I was also checking a solution for accessing the values of Database which written in HTML5 phonegap using Java. In my application there is a requirement to send a parameter to server even the App closed (not resume completely closed). Its possible only using Java right ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
File databaseFile = this.getDatabasePath("databasename");
```

getDatabasePath will tell you where the database is located.

Comment: I try this before, I not even able to access the databases folder created in cordova-sqlite-storage